# jquery get js triggered events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a input element that when you click opens a modal with a table where you can pick a line and a js function changes the input element's value for the selected element. I need to detect the change event on the input element but as the change event is triggered via js the event listener I suspect it's not detecting the change.

This is my function:

```js
$(document).on('change', '#generation_id_display', function(event) {
  console.log('change');
  $('.quote_row input').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-line focused">
  <label for="generation_id" class="form-label">Gen</label>
  <input class="true_value" name="generation_id" id="generation_id_display" style="">
</div>
```

I have no access to the js function that opens the modal and changes the input value.

Comment: Normally you should get a change event in that moment the JS script is changing the value of the input field with val() or text(). So this might not be your problem. Perhaps the js code is also adding a change event listener and stops propagation? What is this js function? Is it a framework?

Comment: It's a js minimized that came with a Laravel module. The module it's from 2015 and the company that made it up no longer exists or provide support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally neither found a solution to my issue neither an explanation of what caused the issue. So to move on and keep working I opted to capture the click inside the table on the modal.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as per the [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/change/):

> Note: Changing the value of an input element using JavaScript, using `.val()` for example, won't fire the event.

The choices given that you have no influence over the JS that modifies the value are limited.

You could use some kind of timer to monitor the value of the input and respond if it changes.  The snippet below shows this in action:

```js
$(document).on('input', '#generation_id_display', function (event) {
  ProcessInputChanged();
});

setInterval(function() {
  $('#generation_id_display').val('test');
}, 2500);

function CheckInputChanged() {
  if ($('#generation_id_display').val() !== '') {
    ProcessInputChanged();
  } else {
    setTimeout(CheckInputChanged, 250);
  }
}

function ProcessInputChanged() {
  console.log('Input changed to ' + 
$('#generation_id_display').val());
}

CheckInputChanged();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-line focused">
  <label for="generation_id" class="form-label">Gen</label>
  <input class="true_value" name="generation_id" id="generation_id_display" style="">       
</div>
```

This code automatically updates the value of the input after 2.5 seconds (to simulate what is happening in your situation).

At the same time, a timer with a 250ms interval is created in the `CheckInputChanged` function that checks whether the value of the input is empty.  If the value is empty, the timer starts again and the function is called again after 250ms.

If the value is not empty, the `ProcessInputChanged` function is called and the timer does not start again (so it will only catch a change once).

If you continually need to track changes made by JS then you will have to modify the code further to track the previous value of the input and always start the timer again (but your description doesn't sound like you need that).

If the input value is changed normally then the `input` event will fire (which you should be using instead of `change`) and will also call `ProcessInputChanged`.

Comment: When loading the form changes the input value to test but when I select a value from the table does not detect the event.

Comment: @jcobo1 I'm not certain what you mean. I've just run the snippet above and the console shows `Input changed to xxx` whenever the value of the input is changed.

Comment: yes but I have js script that when you click on the input text open a modal with a table to select a value. When you select a value stores the selected value inside the input text. This is the event I'm trying to catch.

Comment: @jcobo1 Of course, your script is different.  The working example I've shown you above is designed to illustrate a way of achieving your ambition.  It's not the finished, production code - you need to take the elements of my example and put them into your own code.

Comment: yes that's what I'm working on but as I can not touch the other js script  my action radio is limited. I'll try another approach by capturing the click on the modal table. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @jcobo1 My solution doesn't involve modifying the other code that you can't touch!  Changing the value of the input at 2.5seconds is a _simulation_ designed to show the code working when the input value is changed by JS.  You don't need that part in your code because it's already done by JS when the modal is opened.  How can that not be obvious?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, if you want to click to open other elements, then you should not use change, but use focus.

Because change needs to wait for you to enter the string and leave the input to trigger, and focus will be triggered immediately when you click on the input

Like the example below, is this the effect you want?

```js
$(document).on('focus', '#generation_id_display', function (event) {
    console.log('focus');
    $('.quote_row input').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quote_row"><input type="text" disabled></div>
<div class="form-line focused">
    <label for="generation_id" class="form-label">Gen</label>
    <input class="true_value" name="generation_id" id="generation_id_display" style="">       
</div>
```

Comment: I tried but it's not working it's not detecting the focus event

Comment: ok Then I suspect that the problem may not be so simple, let us rule out other problems such as jquery or duplicate id, we use Vanilla JavaScript to do a basic check

Comment: const input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('focus', (event) => {
  console.log('work');
});

Comment: Then simply click on each input element on the web page, let’s see if it will trigger